# What is the "[full path]" component of the SSL Certificate Authority given by MySQL and PostgreSQL (boto3) calls in the AWS docs?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, boto3, amazon-rds

In the AWS documentation for "[Connecting to your DB instance using IAM authentication and the AWS SDK for Python (Boto3)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Python.html)", the following call is made to both `psycopg2.connect` (shown) and `mysql.connector.connect`:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=ENDPOINT, port=PORT, database=DBNAME, user=USR, password=token, sslmode='prefer', sslrootcert="[full path]rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT now()""")
query_results = cur.fetchall()
print(query_results)
```

I see some discussion about the `ssl_ca` path ([here](https://serverfault.com/questions/988404/update-your-amazon-rds-ssl-tls-certificates-by-october-31-2019) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html)) and what those bundles are used for.  But none of the three links I've given here describe the `[full path]` component given by the AWS docs, or where it is pointing to.  My current guess (from the second link) is [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem) URL, but I'd like to be sure.

Additionally, what are the advantages to having this bundle downloaded to the remote EC2 on which these Python 3 (boto3) scripts are running?

EDIT: By the way, the above call to `psycopg2.connect` is working in Jupyter with Python 3.9.5 on an EC2 currently, with the `[full path]` written as-is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the '[full path]' with the filesystem path (directory path) to where you saved the pem file when you downloaded it (from that last URL you gave) to the local computer.

The advantage of using it is that your client will verify it connected to the correct database, and not some malicious system which is intercepting your traffic.  I don't how advantageous you consider this: if someone has compromised Amazon enough to be intercepting their internal traffic, they might also have compromised their CA as well.  But there is at least some possibility they did one without the other.

Your code as shown does not work for me, because ssl_ca is not how it is spelled.  Assuming you used the code actually given at your first link for PostgreSQL:

```
sslmode='prefer', sslrootcert="[full path]rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem"
```

Then the reason it works despite the bogus path is that "prefer" means it doesn't care if the rootcert is missing, it just skips validating in that case.  If you change it to 'verify-full', then presumably it would stop working.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the issue- I had taken the MySQL snippet instead of the PostgreSQL version.  So download that bundle, put it in (eg) `/home/user/cert/` and then use that full (not relative) path as the `sslrootcert` param...?